# Setting variable the error Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running the below C# code :

```
Excel.Workbook s_workbook = sApp.Workbooks.Open(s_file);
Excel._Worksheet s_ws = s_workbook.Worksheets[1];
string strst = s_ws.Cells[17][1].Value.ToString();
```

But I get this error when setting the variable `strst` in the last line in my above code:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I tried doing this `string strst = s_ws.Cells[17][1].Value.Convert.ToString();` but I get the same error. Any advice?

Comment: First of all, set a breakpoint and check what exactly is null. Also you can allow nulls with `s_ws.Cells[17][1]?.Value?.ToString()`

Comment: What is s_ws in the debugger when you break on that line, before executing that line?  Is it null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems either the `Value` or `Cells[17][1]` are null, you can try something like this:

```
string strst = s_ws.Cells[17][1]?.Value?.ToString();
```

It is called [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

> The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. That is, if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible in the same statement to set the value to empty string "" instead of null if null was found? without using a normal if condition?

Comment: Cause I have the same thing in many parts of my project which is sometimes in if conditions or setting variables,....so it will be very handy to replace it with "" if found null to avoid this happening

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to give me an example of it in your answer please? Thanks again

Comment: @Tak Something like this `string strst = s_ws.Cells[17][1]?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;`